# CMake/CTest Code coverage check

Tags: c++, testing, cmake, code-coverage, ctest

I can run a coverage check using cmake following [this](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CTest/Coverage) wiki page. This is very simple and a setting a dashboard I can have a nice view of code coverage on my browser (latter part). But I don't want to ctest everytime just to check the progress of a single file. In fact, I want to check code coverage locally for a subdirectoy rather than enitre library with thirdparty code.

So, how can we check the code coverage for a subdirectory. Of course,  I had a written a test in cmakelists.txt using add_test(....).

I will try to explain a little bit without any code.

```cmake
Class A {   
public:    
    A() {}

....     
so many methods ..
....

protected:
    ~A() {} 
}; //end class A
```

Next I've written a test:

```cmake
//testA
int main()
{
    A *a = new A();

    a->method1();

    a->method2();
    ...
}
```

Now in CMakeLists.txt, I have:

```
add_test(testA ...)
```

So when I run ctest it will run all test including `TestA`. Of course, I can use `ctest -R "TestA"`.

Now coming back to the question, how can I check coverage of `class A` only. without running all test or just running only `testA`?

Answer (score 2):

I have created a cmake script that generates coverage data meant to be used for the http://coveralls.io/ service (free for open source projects).

The script allows you to specify exactly what files you want to gather the code coverage from (compared to most scripts that lets you exclude files). So you could `file(GLOB` the files you're interested in or specify them manually. This script can also be modified to simply run lcov and generate local html reports instead.

https://github.com/JoakimSoderberg/coveralls-cmake
https://github.com/JoakimSoderberg/coveralls-cmake-example

If http://coveralls.io/ doesn't interest you, here's another script that uses lcov to simply generate local html reports:

https://github.com/bilke/cmake-modules/blob/master/CodeCoverage.cmake